# download video from right click disabled website on Xvast Browser

Tags: right-click, inspect-element

I want to download video from a right click disabled website on xvast browser.
Inspect element doesn't appear by pressing "F12 key" or "ctrl+shift+I"
Extension doesn't work on website.
How can I resolve these issues? I want to download videos from that website.